# Whats the Right way to mange Code deployement and management for AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, deployment, bigdata, emr

we are on boarding very new on to AWS EMR's and **we are looking at the right code repositories and automated code deployment tools**. Is there a right tool for doing these where we can manage end-to-end in terms of code deployments.

primarily we are writing Shell scripts, python scripts and hive scripts.

Any suggestions or pointers or examples will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sundeep

Answer (score 0):

I use a script written with http://capistranorb.com/ with "ec2group" to deploy autoscalling instances via ASG

Here is small info how to integrate "ec2group" https://github.com/smart-gamma/aws-multiply-deploy